# np.where iterate through multiple options in conditionals - lengths must match error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements

I would like the code to iterate through the options in my conditionals so that I don't have to copy and paste the same code chuck over and over with just the conditional altered.

This is my code chuck:

```
for row in range(0, len(all_data)):
    all_data['Zone'] = np.where((all_data['Freq'] == [60, 132]) &
                                (all_data['YMD'] == ['2019-11-05 00:00:00', '2019-11-18 00:00:00']) &
                                (all_data['observation'] == ['2', '2']), ['u', 'u'],
                                [all_data['Zone'], all_data['Zone']])
```

However, I get the following error and traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>    line 3319, in  run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "", line 4, in 
>       (all_data['YMD'] == ['2019-11-05 00:00:00', '2019-11-18 00:00:00']) &   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops__init__.py",
>   line 1179, in wrapper
>       res_values = dispatch_to_index_op(op, self, other, pd.DatetimeIndex)   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops__init__.py",
>   line 630, in dispatch_to_index_op
>       result = op(left_idx, right)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimelike.py",
>   line 132, in wrapper
>       result = op(self._data, maybe_unwrap_index(other)) File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py",
>   line 182, in wrapper raise ValueError("Lengths must match")
>   ValueError: Lengths must match

It looks like the error is " ValueError: lengths must match". I tried to fix this error by duplicating the replacement value "u" and the location of the replacement "all_data['Zone']", but this obviously did not fix the issue.
I'm not really sure where I went wrong or how to fix the issue. If someone has an alternative solution to using np.where that reaches the same objective, I am open to that solution.

**EDIT1- Added example data**

```
Freq    YMD     Zone    observation

60  10/21/2019     A    1

60  10/21/2019     A    2

60  11/5/2019      A    1

60  11/5/2019      A    2

60  11/18/2019     0    1

60  11/18/2019     0    2

132 10/10/2019     A    2

132 10/21/2019     A    1

132 10/21/2019     A    2

132 11/5/2019      A    1

132 11/5/2019      A    2

132 11/18/2019     A    1

132 11/18/2019     A    2

170 8/31/2019      A    1

170 8/31/2019      N    2

170 9/1/2019       N    1
```

**EDIT2- Added example expected output**

```
Freq    YMD     Zone    observation

60  10/21/2019     A    1

60  10/21/2019     A    2

60  11/5/2019      A    1

60  11/5/2019      u    2

60  11/18/2019     0    1

60  11/18/2019     0    2

132 10/10/2019     A    2

132 10/21/2019     A    1

132 10/21/2019     A    2

132 11/5/2019      A    1

132 11/5/2019      A    2

132 11/18/2019     A    1

132 11/18/2019     u    2

170 8/31/2019      A    1

170 8/31/2019      N    2

170 9/1/2019       N    1
```

**Edit3- clunky code that meets objective**
This code does what I need, but I don't want to have to copy and paste the code chucks over and over for each new "freq" and "YMD" combo. I would like to just have a list in the conditionals to iterate through. i.e., if I have 6 different "Freq" and "YMD" combinations, I would have to paste the code block 6 time and just change the conditionals. It could make the code very long and sloppy looking with enough conditional combinations.

```
all_data['Zone'] = np.where((all_data['Freq'] == 60) &
                            (all_data['YMD'] == '2019-11-05 00:00:00') &
                            (all_data['observation'] == '2'), 'u',
                            all_data['Zone'])
all_data['Zone'] = np.where((all_data['Freq'] == 132) &
                            (all_data['YMD'] == '2019-11-18 00:00:00') &
                            (all_data['observation'] == '2'), 'u',
                            all_data['Zone'])
```

Comment: 1. it doesn't seem right using `np.where` inside a `for` loop. 2. `all_data['Freq'] == [60, 132]` shouldn't work unless your data only have 2 rows.

Comment: Ok, how do I get it to iterate through all rows looking for option 1  and replace and then option 2 through option X and replace. I currently only show 2 options, but theoretically, there could be more.

Comment: I have used np.where is for loop when there is a single option for the conditional and I need the rows to update and np.where sequentially. Specifically, when a conditional is dependent on the previous row.

Comment: Please add your expected output from your sample data.

Comment: I added expected output

Comment: For `np.where(cond, A, B)`, each piece is evaluated before being used together by `where`.  And you `cond` is composed of several comparison's joined by `&`.  That's a lot of pieces that you have to get right before the `where` action.  Isolate the one(s) is giving an error, and work to get that right.

Comment: The error talks about `datetimes`.  There's a test for `all_data['YMD']` against 2 dates.  That looks like it could generate a lengths match error.

Comment: @hpaulj If I split the list, so there is only one option, the conditionals work fine. I think its a problem iterating through the list or np.where cant take a list within each conditional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in testing a `Series` (dataframe column) against several values at once, as in `(all_data['Freq'] == [60, 132])`

Make a simple series:

```
In [190]: s = pd.Series(['a','b','c','b','d'])                                                   
In [191]: s                                                                                      
Out[191]: 
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    b
4    d
dtype: object
```

test it against one value:

```
In [192]: s=='a'                                                                                 
Out[192]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

This a nice boolean series that can be combined with another test.  You use `&` to combine tests on different columns, but I gather from the 'clunky' example that you want an `|` 'or' combination for one column:

```
In [193]: (s=='a')|(s=='b')                                                                      
Out[193]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

You are running into problems when trying to do that 'or' test this way:

```
In [194]: s==['a','b']                                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-194-a889b3de7e64> in <module>
----> 1 s==['a','b']

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
   1205             # as it will broadcast
   1206             if other.ndim != 0 and len(self) != len(other):
-> 1207                 raise ValueError("Lengths must match to compare")
   1208 
   1209             res_values = na_op(self.values, np.asarray(other))

ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

The 5 values of `s` don't fit with the 2 on the RHS.

If you do the test row by row, it runs, though the result has a 'and' logic, not 'or'.  The row has to match both strings, which it can't:

```
In [195]: for row in s: 
     ...:     print(row==['a','b']) 
     ...:                                                                                        
False
False
False
False
False
```

`numpy` and `pandas` does implement `broadcasting` which allows us to do more complicated tests.  Using `values`, the numpy array derived from the Series I can do:

```
In [197]: s.values[:,None]==['a','b']                                                            
Out[197]: 
array([[ True, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False, False]])
In [198]: _.any(axis=1)                                                                          
Out[198]: array([ True,  True, False,  True, False])
```

the same True/False sequence as in `Out[193]`

An alternative to the copy and paste would be a parameterized comparison:

```
for a,b,c in [(60,'2019...','2'),(52,'2020...','3')]:
    all_data['Zone'] = np.where((all_data['Freq'] == a) &
                            (all_data['YMD'] == b) &
                            (all_data['observation'] == c), 'u',
                            all_data['Zone'])
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for your solution?

Comment: I will try this tomorrow when back in office

Comment: Sorry, for the delayed accept. The parameterized comparison is a different solution than I was expecting but works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

np.where is trying to match exact values, is this your intention? Can you post example data, my assumption is that one of the dataframe elements are not the equal lenght(e.g.probably the date should be between the two listed times? But instead are checked against a list with 2 elements of the dates).

```
(all_data['YMD'] > '2019-11-05 00:00:00' & all_data['YMD'] < '2019-11-18 00:00:00']) &
```

Comment: I am trying to match exact values. Will post sample data in a few minutes

Comment: I added example data

Comment: Thanks :) I think it is still not very clear what the data operation will be. Are you updating Zone? Are you trying to replace values?   for instance  `all_data['Zone'] = np.where((all_data['Freq'] ==  [60, 132])  `  will fail immediately, because Freq has single value, and you are trying to match it with a list of two values hence the length difference. I see from the other comment you are trying to replace, so maybe in the case of `all_data['Freq'] == [60, 132]` you meant replace the value 60 with 132?

Comment: Yes, I need to update the zone specification based on the conditionals because there are new zones since the original raw data was collected and we don't want to alter the raw data.

Comment: I have added expected output which may clear things up